# Find a character in a variable and remove it

Tags: python, variables, maya

I'm writing a script for maya, it's in python, but this should relate to most things.

If I run my script on the left side of a setup the values for translation etc will be something like 29.292 or 68.215.

The problem is that the right side is a mirror, so it's -29.292 or -68.215.

I need to check if the symbol '-' exists within the variable and if so remove it.

How do I do this?

Thank you

Comment: If your variables are numeric you can just use `abs(x)`.

Answer (score 3):

use `abs()` in case if it's a number , and In case of string use `lstrip()`:

```
In [3]: x=-29.292

In [4]: x=abs(x)

In [5]: x
Out[5]: 29.292000000000002

In [6]: x='-29.292'         #if it's a string

In [7]: x.lstrip('-')
Out[7]: '29.292'
```

Answer (score -1):

Good suggestion. Something user1090427 should watch for is how you they're rounding, if that's an issue at all. Removing the sign before/after rounding can have unexpected results. floor(abs(-29.29)) is 29, and not the same as abs(floor(-29.29)), which is 30.

Comment: I'm a little confused... I don't want to round the number. My software can take a 16 floating point value... Does abs round the number up?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I originally meant this as a comment to Ashwini's answer, not an answer in it's own right.

But IF you are going to do any rounding you need to consider it. The abs function itself does not do any rounding, but int() rounds towards zero, while floor() and ceiling() round towards the next lowest or highest integer respectively, which is different.